# Why do contracts start with nonce 1?

Tags: contract-deployment, nonce

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/764/do-contracts-also-have-a-nonce). The accepted answer says:

> Yes, contracts have nonces. **A nonce of a contract is only incremented
>   when that contract creates another contract** [...].
>   When a contract invokes a function on another contract, a so called
>   "internal transaction" (in http://live.ether.camp), the nonce is not
>   incremented.
>
> The nonce can be obtained by using `web3.eth.getTransactionCount`.

So far, so good. But when I use `web3.eth.getTransactionCount` with a recently deployed contract, the value is 1, not 0, despite that contract not having created any other contract.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-161.md:

> a. Account creation transactions and the CREATE operation SHALL, prior
>   to the execution of the initialisation code, increment the nonce over
>   and above its normal starting value by one (for normal networks, this
>   will be simply 1, however test-nets with non-zero default starting
>   nonces will be different).

This is a fairly recent change, which explains why you can find older contracts with a nonce of 0.

As to the why, my (limited) understanding is that it's an attempt to make sure that "empty" accounts and "non-existent" accounts are the same (zero nonce, zero balance, and empty code), which allows for clean-up of empty accounts.

Answer (score 1):

@smarx found the answer with EIP 161.

Before EIP 161 contract nonces do start at 0.  <s>You are probably passing in your address instead of the contract's address to `web3.eth.getTransactionCount` (or the contract you passed in did create another contract).</s>

Here's an example of a contract that has a nonce of 0.

```
> web3.eth.getTransactionCount('0xab7c74abc0c4d48d1bdad5dcb26153fc8780f83e')
0
```

Comment: See this gist: https://gist.github.com/fvictorio/bc5e0fa302f0812a99f680d7564c7e1e (using web3 1.0). Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it prints "1". I tested it with ganache-cli.

Comment: Thanks for your question and @smarx for answering, and I've updated the answer to https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/764/do-contracts-also-have-a-nonce