# when a contract nonce will increase, and why?

Tags: contract-development, evm, nonce, eoa

when we send a transaction with a EOA, the nonce will increase to ensure the sequence and ...

but mu question is what is nonce in a CA? why we have it? and when and why it increase?

Comment: When it creates another contract. See [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/764/do-contracts-also-have-a-nonce) for more details.