# Keys and addresses terminology

Tags: contract-development, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am trying to understand the difference between these terms  :

- `Wallet`
- `private key`
- `address`

in the ethereum ecosystem, and who contains ( sort of one to many or one to one relationships between classes )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Private key - 256 random bits.
- Public key - 512 bits derived from the private key using ECDSA algorithm.
- Address / account - 160 last bits of the keccak hash of the public key.
- Wallet - usually, software for managing accounts and interacting with the blockchain.

1 address *normally*<sup>1</sup> corresponds to 1 public key and 1 known private key. A wallet can contain multiple addresses.

<sup>1</sup> - as Lingmao Song noted in the comments, 1 address can correspond to multiple public keys and multiple private keys: [Is each Ethereum address shared by (theoretically) 2 ** 96 private keys?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/10055/20451). As lungj noted in the comments, addresses of contracts usually don't have known public/private keys: [Where is the private key for a contract stored?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/185/where-is-the-private-key-for-a-contract-stored)

Comment: "Strictly" speaking, one address can correspond to multiple private keys, see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/10055/20451

Comment: And, while we're strictly speaking, some addresses are used without private keys. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/185/where-is-the-private-key-for-a-contract-stored . (also, multisig wallets straddle the line -- the address itself may have zero known keys, but are accessed using two or more private keys).